# Resharper function to fix naming convention issues

Tags: resharper

A bunch of classes doesn't comply to our naming conventions for private variables. Resharper shows this as a warning, but wants me to fix all of them by hand. Is there some magic option to auto-fix these issues?

'Clean-up code' won't do anything with this. Same goes for converting properties with backing fields to automatic properties when possible: the hint is shown, but Resharper won't fix it automatically.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In more recent versions of ReSharper, this is much easier, but the solution might not be obvious. It wasn't for me!

Here are the steps:

- When an inconsistent naming is detected, ReSharper underlines the symbol in question. Click on it. This will cause a light bulb to appear in the margin.
- Click on the light bulb. The first option should be 'rename to [corrected name]'. To the right, there's an arrow.
- Click the arrow to drill down. From there, you can choose Fix in File, Fix in Project, and so on.

Answer (score 11):

No, resharper will not silently perform an action that alters the behavior of code, only style/aesthetics.

You must actively make functional changes to code.

put your cursor at the top of the file, hold down  <kbd>ALT</kbd> and alternate between <kbd>PAGE DOWN</kbd> to get to the next style issue and  <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to bring up the smart tag to make the change.

use <kbd>SHFT-ALT</kbd> <kbd>PAGE DOWN</kbd> to cycle through errors.

Comment: In fact if it would authomatically correct all the behaviors for you, it wouldn't manage well the exceptions. Resharper gives you the chance to verify that every change is correct and it is very fast to do this verification. Some authomatic changes can be done through Cleanup, then you can do what Sky Sanders tells you in order to do the rest. Fast and easy.

Comment: In version 6.1, the default KB shortcut for next issue is F12 (and ALT-F12 for next error in solution).  I found this annoying, so changed it to ALT-PD as suggested here.  To do this, go to VS Options -> Keyboard. In the awful interface, filter for ReSharper.Resharper_GotoNextHighlight (and Resharper.Resharper_GotoPrevHighlight). Change keys accordingly. Might also do Resharper.Resharper_GotoNextErrorInSolution and Resharper.Resharper_GotoPrevErrorInSolution

Comment: Of course it is nonsense... if ReSharper has the fully parsed AST there is no reason it can't apply the naming styles, except where conflicts are detected. Obviously there would be a caveat that both conflicts and reflection scenarios can't be automatically fixed, but it beats correcting several hundred files by hand when a coworker decides to prefix all local variables with underscores.